# Constructor dependency injection with Dagger2 Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, mvp, dagger-2

I want to inject MyRepositiry class to my MyPresenter. The only thing that I don't quite understand if `@Inject PostRepository mRepository;` would be enough in this case or I need to do this:

```
 public AddPostPresenter(PostRepository postRepository, AddPostContract.View view) {
    this.mRepository = postRepository;
    mView = view;

    mFireBaseApp.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
}
```

---

```
@Module public class DataModule {

    FireBaseApp mFirebaseApp;

    public DataModule(FireBaseApp fireBaseApp) {
        this.mFirebaseApp = fireBaseApp;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    FirebaseAuth getFirebaseAuth() {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    FirebaseUser getCurrentUser(FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        return firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    }
```

My Component:

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = DataModule.class)
    public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
    void inject(PostRepository postRepository);
    void inject(AddPostPresenter addPostPresenter);
    void inject(AddPostActivity addPostActivity);
}
```

Application class:

```
    public class FireBaseApp extends Application {

    private ApplicationComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
        }

        inject();

    }

    private void inject() {
        component = DaggerApplicationComponent
                .builder()
                .dataModule(new DataModule(this))
                .build();
    }

    public ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent(){
        return component;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class PostRepository implements IPosts {

FireBaseApp fireBaseApp;
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

@Inject public PostRepository() {
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
}
```

And finally Presenter:

```
public class AddPostPresenter implements AddPostContract.UserActionListener {

@Inject PostRepository mRepository;
FireBaseApp mFireBaseApp;

private final AddPostContract.View mView;


public AddPostPresenter(PostRepository postRepository, AddPostContract.View view) {
    this.mRepository = postRepository;
    mView = view;

    mFireBaseApp.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
}
```

So again my question is do I need to do this in MyPresenter constructor `mFireBaseApp.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);`
or having PostRepostory with @Inject would be enough? `@Inject PostRepository mRepository;`

Comment: Why are doing `mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();` in `PostRepository` constructor isn't the whole point of dependency injection to have instances 'injected'? `PostRepository` class should have `@Singleton` annotation, and you don't need to get the component as you've exposed it to dagger on the constructor - add all the dependencies for the class into the constructor, and create them in the module only - Dagger can supply them if it knows how to create them!

Comment: So instead of this ```mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();``` I can annotate @Inject FirebaseAuth and FireBaseUser and then just ```mFireBaseApp.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);``` in the constructor?